# authenticate against with Active Directory via samba

Tags: samba

When I login the samba server, it complains:  Access denied. But everything seems OK.I have setup the `krb5.conf`, `samba.conf`, `nsswitch.conf`, and `kinit aduser@DOMAIN.NET`, `wbinfo -a DOMAIN/aduser%thepasswd` works fine, and both of `wbinfo -u` and `wbinfo -g` list the users and groups from AD, and `getent passwd` also list the users from AD. The global section in smb.conf is as following:

```
workgroup = DOMAIN
security = ads
realm = DOMAIN.NET
preferred master = no
encrypt passwords = yes
winbind separator = /
winbind enum users = yes
winbind enum groups = yes
idmap uid = 654321-854321
idmap gid = 654321-854321
template shell = /bin/bash
```

Coud someone kindly give me some suggestion?

Thanks

Leo

Comment: I'm curious that have you joined your box into Windows AD domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED. It seems there is something wrong with winbind separator = /. I comment out this line(this will take the default MS AD separator ) or set winbind separator = + and login with the format: domain\aduser or domain+aduser. It works. Hope this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you this article http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.12.linux.aspx from Microsoft.
The configure file seems OK.